# Probability that two numbers in different numeral system match a pattern

Tags: probability, summation

How likely is it that the following holds true.

$ s_1=\sum_{i=0}^{9}{16^{i} \cdot x_i}$ where $ x_i\in[0,15]\cap\mathbb{N}$ and $x_i=0$ $\forall$ $i \in\{7,6,3,2\}$

$ s_2=\sum_{i=0}^{7}{36^{i} \cdot y_i}$ where $ y_i\in[0,35]\cap\mathbb{N}$ and $y_i=0$ $\forall $ $i \in\{6,5,3,2\}$ and $y_i \neq 0$  $ \forall i \in\{7,4\}$

$s_1 =s_2$

Basically I'm trying to figure out the likely-hood that $s_1$ in base16 with zeros at pos 7,6,3 and 2 has zeros at pos 6,5,3 and 2 in base36 whilst non zero at pos 7 and 4.

$P = \frac{\text{numer of solutions}}{36^2\cdot 35^2}$

Comment: Am I guessing correctly that this has something to do with alpha-numeric combinations (perhaps a password issue), since base $36$ uses all $10$ digits and $26$ letters?

Comment: its not password-related, it concerns the uniqueness of mapping from hex string to alpha-numeric string. I need to make sure that my new mapping does not collide with my old mapping.

Comment: You should change "$\forall$" to "$\iff$", otherwise there is at least one obvious answer here ($s_1=s_2=0$).

Comment: sorry i made a mistake it's supposed to be yi in the second sum

Comment: I fergot to add a restriction.. just a second

Comment: @barakmanos sorry, I had to make some corrections, it describes the problem fully now.

Comment: I've written a program to check all cases and found no matches.

Comment: @user1008646 can you post the source as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a quick program in Delphi.  There were no matches.

```
procedure TForm1.Button8Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I   : integer;
  B16 : string;
  B36 : string;
begin
  // There are 16^6 = 16777216 possible base-16 values.
  // That's 10 digits, 4 of which are forced to zero.

  for I := 0 to $FFFFFF do
    begin
      // BaseToBaseConversion converts a number from one base to another.

      B16 := BaseToBaseConversion
               ( inttostr ( I ), // string in base 10 to convert
                 10,             // convert from base 10
                 16,             // to base 16
                 6   );          // with a minimum of 6 digits in the result.

      // Insert the zeros
     //       x9       x8     x7 x6    x5       x4     x3 x2    x1       x0
      B16 := B16[1] + B16[2] + '00' + B16[3] + B16[4] + '00' + B16[5] + B16[6];

      // Convert from base 16 to base 36, minimum of 8 digits

      B36 := BaseToBaseConversion ( B16, 16, 36, 8 );

      // Check the result

      if     ( B36[1] <> '0' )        // y7
         and ( B36[2]  = '0' )        // y6
         and ( B36[3]  = '0' )        // y5
         and ( B36[4] <> '0' )        // y4
         and ( B36[5]  = '0' )        // y3
         and ( B36[6]  = '0' ) then   // y2

         // Output result
         // *** NEVER HAPPENS ***

           Memo2 . Lines . Add ( B16 + ' = ' + B36 );
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about just trying all the combinations.